# Simplest webview app in iOS - fail to run

Tags: ios, swift, webview, ios-web-app

I am trying to make an ios app that simply open a URL. So basically a webview app. I am using XCode 12.4 and that's what I did:

1. Create new project->iOS App --> (see image below)
2. Create a new file: `ViewController.swift` -->

```
import WebKit
class WebViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!
    
    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = URL(string: "https://developer.apple.com")!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }
}
```

4. Build and Run.

The issue is that the app continues to open on "Hello World" and I imagine the reason is that the `MyappApp.swift` file is calling `ContentView` instead of `ViewController`

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct myappApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

**Disclaimer**: This is my first iOS app and I know little to nothing about iOS dev.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like you are creating a SwiftUI app and not creating an app using UIKit.  I would suggest trying to create an app but select (in the first image you have shown) the interface as storyboard. Then you should be able to work in the default  ViewController class that is created in that project.

Comment: I tried that, but the screen remains white in the app when compaling

Comment: Clearly you are doing something wrong, I suggest that you follow this tutorial https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/4/overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close... Wrap your `WebViewController` in a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` to make it compatible with SwiftUI

```
import SwiftUI
struct WebView_UI: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController {
        let vc = WebViewController()
        return vc
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

And then reference your new SwiftUI `UIViewControllerRepresentable` in a SwiftUI `struct`. For example...

```
struct myappApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            WebView_UI()
        }
    }
}
```

Or...

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Hello World!").padding()
            WebView_UI()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @lorem ipsum, I am having an issue with the first part of the code you posted. Which  file should I add that too? I tried adding it to viewcontroller.swift but I am getting errors: `Cannot find type 'UIViewControllerRepresentable' in scope`

Comment: Any file. Just make sure your `import SwiftUI` at the top of the file. Right now you only have `import WebKit` in that file.

Comment: It seems like  you are very new at this I suggest running though the [Apple SwiftUI tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/) at least once to get started.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: Worked! I now need to make quite some changes, I didn't realize it was going to open without navigation UI